# Редактор модуля HTML-содержимое OpenCart2.3 не сохраняет код

Tags: opencart

В модуле html-содержимое, где в описании можно вставить код, после сохранения сбивается весь код, а следственно и кастомные стили.
вот что я сохраняю:

```
<div class="map_sails">
    <div class="map_sails-wrap">
        <h3>география продаж</h3>
        <div class="map-content">
            <h3>более</h3>
            <p class="number">3500,0</p>
            <p>струн по всей россии каждый год</p>
            <p class="red_underline"></p>
            <h3>свыше</h3>
            <p class="number">5600</p>
            <p>покупателей по всей стране</p>
            <a href="#">подробнее</a>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

а вот это показывает после сохранения:

```
<p>география продаж</p>

<p>более</p>

<p>3500,0</p>

<p>струн по всей россии каждый год</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>свыше</p>

<p>5600</p>

<p>покупателей по всей стране</p>

<p><a href="#">подробнее</a></p>
```

как с этим бороться. стили постоянно слетают и редактировать невозможно

Comment: Ситуация такая: я вставляю код (первый), с классами и нормальной разметкой, сохраняю, перехожу на страницу все хорошо отображает. Но если мне нужно изменить, например, другие цифры, то когда захожу редактировать - исходный код, то там второй вариант кода, с без классов и только теги <p>. Если что-то изменить и сохранить, то все стили теряются.

Comment: не отжимается кнопочка-то, пока там есть код

Answer (score 0):

Отожмите кнопку `Исходный код` `[</>]`, после сохраните изменения.